# How to identify the vf page opened in ipad and mobile devices?

Tags: visualforce, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I want to display the different layouts for Desktop & Mobile. I am using '$User.UITheme' to identify the browser. But my problem is, for mobile device and IPAD both are returning 'Theme4t'. But i need same layout for Desktop & IPAD. Is there seperate way to identify the IPAD...?

Below is the link followed to identifying the browser.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_useruitheme.htm

Comment: if you want to apply css based on screen size then you should go with media query

Comment: @ManjotSingh, It is not with css based.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery